# Remover casos duplicados e manter valores específicos de uma outra variável

Tags: r

Considere a seguinte situação:

Tenho um banco de dados com duas variáveis. A primeira é uma variável com valores duplicados (ex. CPFxxx.xxx.xxx-xx aparece  14 vezes, CPFxxx.xxx.xxx-xx aparece 18 vezes e assim por diante). A segunda variável são as datas de ocorrência do evento (ex. 2017-01-18, 2017-01-19...) associada a cada CPF.

Uso a função a seguir para remover os casos duplicados:

```
new<-dataset[!duplicated(dataset[c("CPFs")]),]
```

E consigo remover as linhas duplicadas.

Meu objetivo: remover as duplicações em `CPFs`, mas, na outra variável (`data`), fazer com que as mais recentes (ou as mais antigas) permaneçam atreladas ao CPF. Isto é, preciso estabelecer uma ordenação no momento da execução da função.

Assim, se tenho as datas (`2018-01-20; 2017-02-22`) atreladas a um CPF, a data atrelada a ele seria: `2017-02-22`.

`dput` fictício para auxíliar a resposta:

```
dataset=structure(list(CPFs = c(1234, 2345, 1234, 2345, 1234, 2345, 1234, 
2345), date = c(1998, 1997, 1993, 1992, 1998, 1998, 1992, 1989
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Resultado desejado:

```
CPF  date
1234 1992
2345 1989
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma de simples de resolver é utilizando o pacote `dplyr`, do `tidyverse`:

```
  new_dataset <- dataset %>% 
    arrange(date) %>% 
    distinct(CPFs, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Preste atenção que é necessário que as datas estejam formatadas como `Date`, e não como string, do contrário a classificação pode não funcionar adequadamente.

Caso queira selecionar a observação mais recente, basta utilizar `arrange(desc(date))`, ou seja, classificando de forma descendente.

Comment: De fato, a função `arrange` do `dplyr` resolve. Grato, @Davi.